# Connection refused when calling API hosted on Amazon from PHP HTTP client

Tags: php, http, amazon-ec2, https

I have an API hosted on a web server running on amazon EC2 on port 5001. when I call the API from the chrome browser it works, but when I call it from PHP HTTP client I get the error:

```
Failed to connect to [my public domain].compute.amazonaws.com port 5001: Connection refused
```

- The web server is running on HTTP, not HTTPS.
- For the EC2 instance security group, I have added a rule for `Custom TCP` for port 5001.
- When I use the same HTTP client on other website i.e. www.google.com it works fine.

below is my PHP source code to request the EC2-hosted API.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$server_output = curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
   print curl_error($ch); 
} 
curl_close($ch); 


if ($server_output == "OK") { echo "ok"; } else { echo $server_output; }
?>
```

What is wrong with this setup?

Comment: Probably refusing because of ssl verification.

Comment: @Dlk it was reloved by opening port 5001 for the outgoing requests on PHP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was reloved by opening port 5001 for the outgoing requests on the PHP web server that was blocked by the firewall.